# Couldn't find Order with 'id'=2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, shopping-cart

I have recently changed my database from sqlite3 to Postgres so I could launch it to Heroku. Thus I made all the changes to my database and Gemfile, and lauched. The Heroku app is working well, but when I go back to my local branch I am triggering this error.

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Devise::SessionsController#new

**Couldn't find Order with 'id'=2**

```
def current_order
   if !session[:order_id].nil?
      Order.find(session[:order_id])
   else
      Order.new
   end
```

Which has me confused because a) Again the Heroku app is working well.  and b) Because the conditional clearly states that if order id is nil it should just Make a new order. Why would it freak out if it can't find the id? 
As you can see, I am using devise. Here are my cart-relevant models:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @order_items = current_order.order_items
  end
end


class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.new(order_item_params)
    @order.save
    session[:order_id] = @order.id
  end

  def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end
private
  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :subproduct_id)
  end
end
```

And the models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
private
  # Sets order status of 1, in progress.
  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end
end




class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subproduct
  belongs_to :order

  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validate :subproduct_present
  validate :order_present

  before_save :finalize


  # Will use the associated subproduct's price if the order item is not persisted
  def unit_price
    if persisted?
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      subproduct.price
    end
  end

  def total_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end

private
  def subproduct_present
    if subproduct.nil?
      errors.add(:subproduct, "is not valid or is not active.")
    end
  end

  def order_present
    if order.nil?
      errors.add(:order, "is not a valid order.")
    end
  end

  def finalize
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
    self[:total_price] = quantity * self[:unit_price]
  end
end




class OrderStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have `Order` record with `id = 2` in your ***local DB*** ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. The console tells me that I do not. But I not understand why it should even search for it.

Comment: It's because in your `order_items` table there could be a record with `order_id = 2`. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locally, your session still has the `order_id` key set to `2`. That's why your code passes the if-check and gets to the `Order.find` call. The reason why it blows up is because the default behavior of `find` is now to raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if it can't find a matching record.

Now, that's probably also the correct behavior for your website. If somehow a session is tied to an order that doesn't exist, you'd be in an inconsistent state! I think you're seeing this now because you rebuilt your database, wiping the order record that your session was tied to, but haven't cleared your session. If you do so (e.g. by deleting all cookies for your localhost domain, or by closing your browser fully and re-opening it), the error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't find Order with 'id'=2

The error is because there is no `Order` record with `id = 2` in your ***local DB*** and there could be a ***child record*** in your `order_items` table with `order_id = 2`. So the `session[:order_id]` won't be ***nil*** and it finds the `Order` record with `id = 2` which didn't exist.

The reason could be because the `Order` record with `id = 2` may be accidentally deleted. For a quick fix, try clearing all the cookies or try deleting the `order_items` record with `order_id = 2` and make sure every `order_items` record have a correct `order_id` that corresponding to ***existing order record***.

Comment: And a thank you to you too sir. May you also have a satisfying Saturday.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cookies, as you've been told, that would cause a possible problem. You could also do this. What it does is check if the order found in the cookie is still available, if not, it will reset it then create a new one without throwing an error

```
def current_order
if !session[:order_id].nil?
  @find_order = Order.find(session[:order_id]) rescue nil
  if !@find_order
    session[:order_id] = nil
    current_order
  elsif @find_order.order_status_id != 1
    session[:order_id] = nil
    current_order
  else
    Order.find(session[:order_id])
  end
else
  Order.new
end
```

end